# Close button doesn't work in modal image as I can't change back to display: none with JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of image cards in an array and I would like to open their detail as modal.

I have placed `display: none` by default in **#myModal** CSS.

Now I wrote some JS code to change the `display = block` and it works

The problem is I couldn't close it when I click the close button by changing the **#myModal** display to `none`.

The display CSS value is still `block` even after I **clicked** **`x`**.

See my screenshot from the Google development console

[image: Screenshot of Google Console]

Please see my js code below and any help would be really appreciated.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal")

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content-grid-container")

// Get the detail class inside content block
var detail = document.querySelector(".detail")

Array.from(content).forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {

    modal.style.display = "block"
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // click to close the modal
    closeBtn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none"
      console.log(modal.style)
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: Event propagation might be the issue here, Can you please add a minimum reproducible code, so that someone willing to help can suggest a fix? Posting JS alone won't be of much help.

Comment: Can you share your HTML too?

Comment: My HTML file is connected with database. Therefore, I am not sure how you would reproduce the it.

Anyway, I will share the HTML structure here :

https://codepen.io/Htet-Yan/pen/qBRNwRd

Comment: does `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]` find the right element? One another note, if there is only one close button on page, consider moving 'var closeBtn..` code all the way to `onclick` handler outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes @eamanola, Already tried every places. The error still exits. :(

Comment: can you share the HTML for the `#myModal` and `.close` please

Comment: I have placed everything in this codepen link just to show you the codes. I put comment in CSS. Please find with the word "modal" in the CSS tab. Thanks
https://codepen.io/Htet-Yan/pen/qBRNwRd

Comment: @Htet it is a event loop issue. enclose the click handler in timeout. `closeBtn.onclick = function() { setTimeout(() => { modal.style.display = "none"; console.log(modal.style); }); }`

Comment: @eamanola. Thanks a lot . I will try this out first and will update here